# MVC 1.0.0.0: Where can I get a copy of the DLL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The stupid project i am working on requires this dll, does anyone know where I can get it from? I have tried a few sites but they're all past 1.0.0.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you install it
(You can d/l from - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5388)

You'll have it on your computer here-

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies